# Linux - open multiple terminals from one sh file

Tags: terminal, command

I'm trying to run 4 terminal windows at the same time by running one .sh file.
My .sh file contains:

xterm -e "command1"

xterm -e "command2"

xterm -e "command3"

xterm -e "command4"

Any help would be much appreciated. THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

append **&** to each command

```
xterm -e "command1" &
xterm -e "command2" &
xterm -e "command3" &
xterm -e "command4" &
```

the '&' puts the job in the background which 'frees' it from your terminal so the next command can run